# Huge gaps between printf statements in command console while getting user input char

Tags: c

Why command center is creating huge gap when I try to enter char ? Aim of program is to enter side length of square and fill it with entered character.
Thank you !

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

void sides(void);

int main(void) {
    sides();
    return 0;
}

void sides(void) {
    int input;
    char inputChar;
    printf("Enter sides of parking lot:  ");
    scanf_s("%d", &input);
    printf("Enter desired character:  ");
    scanf_s("%c", &inputChar, 1);
    int x, y;
    while (input != -1) {
        for (y = 0; y < input; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < input; x++) {
                printf("%c",inputChar);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("Enter sides of parking lot:  ");
        scanf_s("%d", &input);
        printf("Enter desired character:  \n");
        scanf_s("%c", &inputChar, 1);
    }
}
```

I expected

```
Enter sides of parking lot: 5
Enter desired character: *
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

What I get is following with not intentional gap

```
Enter sides of parking lot:  5
Enter desired character:





























Enter sides of parking lot:  *
Enter desired character:
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
Enter sides of parking lot:
```

Comment: Add a space before `%c` in the format string for `scanf` so it skips leading whitespace. Otherwise it is reading the leftover newline from the previous input. `" %c"`

Comment: Your programs output seems to work as expected, if I enter a number and a non-whitespace character e.g. "4*", WITHOUT any white space character in between, e.g. a newline/return. Your input is a little weird, because giving the character is needed before being prompted.

Answer (score 1):

Your `scanf("%c", &inputChar)` (well, your `scanf_s`, but I surmise is does the same thing. But `scanf_s` is non standard, and I have no mean to test it), is reading the trailing `\n` of the previous input.

When you `scanf("%d", &input)`, it reads only what constitute an integer, so digits.
But what you typed on your keyboard was some digits and then a RETURN (`'\n'`). The `\n` is still there in the buffer, waiting to be read.

One simple way around this, assuming that you won't want the `inputChar` to be a space, is to replace
`scanf("%c", &inputChar)`
by
`scanf(" %c", &inputChar)`

Then `scanf` will assume that you are interested not just in the next char, but in the next char after some separators (spaces, and `\n`)

If you need the ability to have a space in `inputChar`, that is if you want the user to be able to reply with a space to the question "input desired characters", then you'll have to loop the reading of `inputChar` until you get something else that a `\n`

```c
for(;;){
    scanf("%c", &inputChar);
    if(inputChar!='\n' && inputChar!='\r') break;
}
```